# NHibernate join single value from other table

Tags: .net, nhibernate, join, nhibernate-mapping

I'm trying to get nHibernate to join the name of the structure that is stored in separate table into the structure POCO object.

The database looks something like this:

```
+-----------+  +------------+  +-----------+
| Structure |  | Texts      |  | Languages |
+===========+  +============+  +===========+
| Id        |  | Id         |  | Id        |
| NameId    |  | LanguageId |  | Name      |
| FieldA    |  +------------+  +-----------+
| FieldB    |
+-----------+
```

I would like the POCO object to look like the following:

```
public class Structure
{
    public Structure()
    {
    }

    public long Id
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public string FieldA
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public string FieldB
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    private long id;
    private string name;
    private string fieldA;
    private string fieldB;
}
```

So what I am trying to achive is to get the name property of the POCO object joined in from the Texts table with the following criteria:

```
Texts.Id=Structure.NameId AND Texts.Id=CurrentLanguageId
```

(CurrentLanguageId would be stored in the application and mapped into nHibernate)

So how to map this join in nHibernate and how to inject a property from the application into the join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to localize your NHibernate queries, take a look at [this](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/12/26/LocalizingNHibernateContextualParameters.aspx).